# Htaccess block all incoming methods except GET for all Urls except one?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to block all request with POST, DELETE, ... methods but GET and for all Urls except one or two. Here is my code, I need http://.../api/failure/report to be free and all others be redirected.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/failure/report [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

when I use this code, it works well but I want vice versa.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=GET
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api/failure/report [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^api/failure/report/?$ - [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !GET [NC]
    RewriteRule ^.*$ / [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I test it but it's the same. It just redirect to /

Comment: I even changed it to RewriteRule ^.*/?api/failure/report/?$ - [L] , but same happened.